# React Native Expo app build for iOS simulator crashes on start up

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I've built a React native app with Expo which has been working perfectly fine with Expo Go. As I create a build to use on the iOS simulator, it crashes on start up.

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening as the build with EAS works fine.

I previously managed to upload the build to testflight where the exact same issues were happening. I made a heap of changes to my code, packages etc and nothing seemed to work.

Instead i deleted my project, cloned it from my git repo and started again. This is the first build since.

Here's the problem report with the particular thread that is crashing when using the ios simulator:

Thread 8 Crashed:: com.facebook.react.JavaScript

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b17e40cc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1b18381e8 pthread_kill + 256
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x18012873c abort + 124
3   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x180127bb0 __assert_rtn + 268
4   RomeTravelersGuide                     0x104b95dd8 reanimated::NativeReanimatedModule::scheduleOnUI(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&) + 344
5   RomeTravelersGuide                     0x104b9e4ac reanimated::__hostFunction_NativeReanimatedModuleSpec_scheduleOnUI(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::react::TurboModule&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long) + 40
6   RomeTravelersGuide                     0x104cd1488 std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>::operator()(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long) const + 44
7   hermes                                 0x1065efaa8 0x1065dc000 + 80552
8   hermes                                 0x1066032f8 0x1065dc000 + 160504
9   hermes                                 0x106622438 0x1065dc000 + 287800
10  hermes                                 0x106621b60 0x1065dc000 + 285536
11  hermes                                 0x106663510 0x1065dc000 + 554256
12  hermes                                 0x1065e358c 0x1065dc000 + 30092
13  hermes                                 0x1065e3414 facebook::hermes::HermesRuntime::evaluateJavaScriptWithSourceMap(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::Buffer const> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::Buffer const> const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) + 88
14  hermes                                 0x1065e4464 0x1065dc000 + 33892
15  RomeTravelersGuide                     0x104ccead0 facebook::jsi::WithRuntimeDecorator<facebook::react::(anonymous namespace)::ReentrancyCheck, facebook::jsi::Runtime, facebook::jsi::Runtime>::evaluateJavaScript(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::Buffer const> const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) + 76
16  RomeTravelersGuide                     0x104cfdf70 facebook::react::JSIExecutor::loadBundle(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::JSBigString const, std::__1::default_delete<facebook::react::JSBigString const> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) + 344
17  RomeTravelersGuide                     0x104ca2904 std::__1::__function::__func<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::loadBundle(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry, std::__1::default_delete<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry> >, std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::JSBigString const, std::__1::default_delete<facebook::react::JSBigString const> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)::$_1, std::__1::allocator<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::loadBundle(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry, std::__1::default_delete<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry> >, std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::JSBigString const, std::__1::default_delete<facebook::react::JSBigString const> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)::$_1>, void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>::operator()(facebook::react::JSExecutor*&&) + 144
18  RomeTravelersGuide                     0x104ca37bc std::__1::__function::__func<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::__1::function<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>)::$_8, std::__1::allocator<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::__1::function<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>)::$_8>, void ()>::operator()() + 60
19  RomeTravelersGuide                     0x104bf92d0 facebook::react::tryAndReturnError(std::__1::function<void ()> const&) + 32
20  RomeTravelersGuide                     0x104c04394 facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::tryFunc(std::__1::function<void ()> const&) + 24
21  RomeTravelersGuide                     0x104c0416c invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runAsync(std::__1::function<void ()>) + 44
22  CoreFoundation                         0x18039aa34 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 20
23  CoreFoundation                         0x18039a17c __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 360
24  CoreFoundation                         0x180394f8c __CFRunLoopRun + 2336
25  CoreFoundation                         0x180394254 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 584
26  RomeTravelersGuide                     0x104bee968 +[RCTCxxBridge runRunLoop] + 212
27  Foundation                             0x180bbede0 __NSThread__start__ + 704
28  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1b18384e4 _pthread_start + 116
29  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1b18336cc thread_start + 8
```

---

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "rome-travelers-guide",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@native-html/iframe-plugin": "^2.6.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.21.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api": "^1.0.1",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "events": "^3.3.0",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-localization": "~14.3.0",
    "expo-location": "~16.1.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "^6.7.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.72.6",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-pagination": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.2",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.6.3",
    "react-query": "^3.39.3",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "undefined": "."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I've spent a good 4 months building this app and I've been stuck on this issue for a few days now, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you